# Display tabs on product display page horizontally

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, tabs

I am using magento 1.9.2.3, I want to display the tabs(i.e., Description, Review, Videos etc) in the product display page horizontally. The tabs are currently being displayed vertically.

My website is :

[www.ciaotrips.com](http://www.ciaotrips.com)

Comment: can you share website's URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by applying css like this:

```
.collateral-tabs {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.product-collateral .toggle-tabs {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.product-collateral .toggle-tabs li {
    float: left;
}
```

Apart from this, you can set border according to your choice on tabs.